# Entity framework sharing foreign key in base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

### Problem

I want inherited classes from channel to share same foreign key, merging Gateway_GatewayId and Gateway_GatewayId1 columns into GatewayId column.

**Can it be done?**

[image]

I have tried this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ChannelModbus>().HasRequired(d => d.Gateway).WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.GatewayId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false)
```

But get this error:

> The foreign key component 'GatewayId' is not a declared property on
>   type 'ChannelModbus'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded
>   from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.

And I've tried to use MapKey too:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ChannelModbus>().HasRequired(d => d.Gateway).WithMany()
            .Map(d => d.MapKey("GatewayId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

And get this error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> GatewayId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'GatewayId' is already defined.
>
> GatewayId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'GatewayId' is already defined.

### Code

```
public abstract class Channel
{
    public int ChannelId { get; private set; }
    public int GatewayId { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Gateway
{
    public int GatewayId { get; private set; }
}

public abstract class GatewayTcp : Gateway
{
    public string Ip { get; set; }
    public int Puerto { get; set; }
}

public class GatewayModbus : GatewayTcp { }
public class GatewayXmlRpc : GatewayTcp { }

public class ChannelModbus : Channel
{
    public virtual GatewayModbus Gateway { get; set; }
}

public class ChannelXmlRpc : Channel
{
    public virtual GatewayXmlRpc Gateway { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Channel> Channels { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Gateway> Gateways { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Gateway>().Property(d => d.GatewayId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Gateway>().HasKey(d => d.GatewayId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Channel>().Property(d => d.ChannelId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Channel>().HasKey(d => d.ChannelId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ChannelModbus>().HasRequired(d => d.Gateway).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ChannelXmlRpc>().HasRequired(d => d.Gateway).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        //modelBuilder.Entity<ChannelModbus>().HasRequired(d => d.Gateway).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.GatewayId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<ChannelXmlRpc>().HasRequired(d => d.Gateway).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.GatewayId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just move the `Gateway` property from `ChannelModbus` and `ChannelXmlRpc` to the base class, `Channel`.

```
public abstract class Channel
{
    public int ChannelId { get; private set; }
    public int GatewayId { get; set; }
    public virtual GatewayModbus Gateway { get; set; }
}
```

When you define the property on each derived class, since you use TPH inheritance, all columns will be mapped to a single table, one column belongs to `ChannelModbus` and one column belongs to `ChannelXmlRpc` even though they refer to the same entity. By moving it to the base class, both derived class will use the same column for foreign key.

Comment: But the Gateway property has different type in each channel. ChannelModbus gateway property type is GatewayModBus, and ChannelXmlRpc gateway property type is GatewayXmlRpc. Both inherit from Gateway but have their own properties. I know one solution is using your solution and adding a property with a getter casting to the right type in each channel... but I'm curious about if it can be done in other way.

Comment: I think it's not possible, when using TPH, each property on derived class will be mapped into separated column, you can do validation on application to only allow setting `GatewayModbus` instance to `ChannelModbus::Gateway`, overriding the `SaveChanges` and check the ChangeTracker